# Merge specific files with MergeMKV

Tags: batch, merge

I've been using MKVToolNix GUI for a while and lately I've been utilizing its scripting functionality. I have some TV show files that I ripped and it's one of those shows where they contain 2 sub-episodes per episode (Intro, Episode 1, Episode 2, Outro). The online TV databases count the sub-episodes as full episodes, and so Plex is tagging my episodes all wrong. So I'd like to reassemble them like this (I have the Intro and Outro and sub-episodes all split out):

- Intro + Ep1 + Outro
- Intro + Ep2 + Outro

And so on. I have all the episode files in one folder, and the intro and outro files in another. I've taken a shot at the script, but after playing around with it for a while and reading the official mkvmerge documentation and doing some Googling I'm still struggling.

```
for %%a in (*.mkv) do mkvmerge -o "G:\Ripped Discs\Edited\Output\%%~a" -append-mode file --generate-chapters when-appending "G:\Ripped Discs\Edited\Reserved\Intro.mkv" + "G:\Ripped Discs\Edited\Input\%%~a" + "G:\Ripped Discs\Edited\Reserved\Outro.mkv"
```

As you can see, I'd like to generate chapters for each file. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but hopefully I'm close.

**Edit:**
I ran the script through an AI chatbot and after tweaking it a bit, it's now at least giving me mergemkv error messages, which it wasn't before.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "inputFolder=G:\Ripped Discs\Edited\Input"
set "outputFolder=G:\Ripped Discs\Edited\Output"
set "introFile=G:\Ripped Discs\Edited\Reserved\Intro.mkv"
set "outroFile=G:\Ripped Discs\Edited\Reserved\Outro.mkv"

cd /d "%inputFolder%"

for %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    set "outputFile=!outputFolder!\%%~a"
    mkvmerge -o "!outputFile!" --append-mode file --generate-chapters when-appending "!introFile!" + "%%~a" + "!outroFile!"
)

endlocal
```

The errors appear related to track mappings:

> No append mapping wasgiven for the file no. 1 ('S1E03.mkv'). A default
> mapping of 1:0:0:0,1:1:0:1,1:2:0:2 will be used instead. Please keep
> that in mind if mkvmerge aborts with an error message regarding
> invalid '--append-to' options. No append mapping was given for the
> file no. 2 ('G:\Ripped Discs\Edited\Reserved\Outro.mkv'). A default
> mapping of 2:0:1:0,2:1:1:1,2:2:1:2 will be used instead. Please keep
> that in mind if mkvmerge aborts with an error message regarding
> invalid '--append-to' options. Error: The track number 0 from the file
> 'S1E03.mkv' cannot be appended to the track number 0 from the file
> 'G:\Ripped Discs\Edited\Reserved\Intro.mkv'. The width of the two
> tracks is different: 708 and 710

I will continue investigating but any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run this? What errors or messages do you get?

Comment: No error actually. When I add pause to the end I just see the echoed script and then the pause.

Comment: I haven't worked in batch in 20 years, but I would guess this is an issue with the batch syntax, and not an issue with mkvmerge itself.